# Magento 2 : How to add Coupon Code Section In mini cart like in the shopping cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, coupon-codes, magento2.3.6

I want to display coupon code section inside the minicart with same functionality as shopping cart page.

Comment: You Can add this code in minicart.phtml

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon')->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml')->toHtml();

But this has to be outside minicart-content-wrapper "div" else there will be css conflicts and Apply coupon code option won't work.

Comment: @devhs Thank you! but i want to add this section inside the minicart.

Comment: You can add a simple text field & a button in mini cart first, then on click button you can call api (which can be custom or default) & process the data accordingly.

Comment: @devhs can you please share the answer here in detail if you;ve used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please copy minicart.phtml from your vendor files:**

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

**And overwrite it in your custom theme:**

```
app/design/VenderName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

**After that, add the following line to include the coupon code HTML:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon::class)->setTemplate("Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

**Example File: minicart.phtml (Magento version 2.4.6)**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Cart')) ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false && !isLoading() },
               blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number">
                <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count').toLocaleString(window.LOCALE) --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count').toLocaleString(window.LOCALE) --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
        <div class="block block-minicart"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
            <?php // custom Coupon code ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon::class)->setTemplate("Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml")->toHtml();?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $scriptString = <<<script
            require(['jquery'], function ($) {
                $('a.action.showcart').on('click', function() {
                    $(document.body).trigger('processStart');
                });
            });
script;
        ?>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], 'window.checkout = ' .
     /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedConfig(), false); ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->escapeJs(
                $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))
            ) ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]